# IEEEtran bibliography url accessdate

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I want to modify the line of text which comes before an url when you add a url to your bibliography item.

The default format for the url is

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.yes 'status.cap :=
      name.url.prefix " " *
      "\url{" * url * "}" *
      punct.no 'this.status.punct :=
      punct.period 'prev.status.punct :=
      space.normal 'this.status.space :=
      space.normal 'prev.status.space :=
      quote.no 'this.status.quote :=
    }
  if$
}
```

Now I removed `name.url.prefix " " *` and replaced it with

```
accessdate empty$
  { "[Online]. Available: " * }
  { "[Online; accessed: " * accessdate * "]. Available:" * }
if$
```

And added `accessdate` to the set if `ENTRY` items. When I however now compile it I get the error:

> You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry BIBLIOGRAPHY ITEM

What is the problem here? I noticed that as soon as I add the line `name.url.prefix " " *` back everything works again, also in combination with my added code. I tried removing everything which was associated with `name.url.prefix` but that did not work helas.

Minimal example IEEEtran.cls needed:

document.tex

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
Test \cite{stackexchange}.  
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Bibliography.bib

```
@misc{stackexchange,
  title="Title",
  author="Author",
  year="2014",
  publisher="Someone",
  url="http://tex.stackexchange.com/",
  accessdate="2014-11-04"
}
```

Modified IEEEtran.bst

http://pastebin.com/VQa7V4bx

The url function is on line 1938 and name.url.prefix is used in multiple lines.